# Facebook publish_actions permission doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After I get authentication from the user i add action to his activity that read an article from my site put i get this error :(

```
"(#100) The Action Type lincinewsapp:Read is not approved, so app 223239061119552 can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app.  User 100003803199829 is not one of those roles."
```

Comment: How have you added action to his activity.?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was my mistake, after adding an action Facebook need you to submit the action to use it for other users or it will be used by administrators, developers, and testers of the app only.